# Ударение в фамилии Майков

Tags: фонетика

Где ставить ударение в фамилии Майков?

Comment: А сам вопрос где? И при чем тут орфоэпия?

Comment: Исправляете, так исправляйте правильно, пожалуйста. У нас нет тега "ударение"!

Answer (score 3):

Может быть и там, и там. Если имеете в виду поэта Аполлона Николаевича Майкова, то ударение на первый слог, мАйков.